# Android: Why isn't my ArrayAdapter getting populated?

Tags: java, android, adapter

For my program in Android I want to use simple ArrayAdapter, without overriding the ArraYAdapter class. The problem is that the adapter is not being showed on the activity.

```
    ArrayList<String> myList = generateListAndTaskText(intent);
    final ListView myListView =  (ListView) findViewById(R.id.widget_show_task_act_subtasks_listview);
    Log.d("ShowTaskAct", myList.size() + "");   //Log shows 2 items
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.main_child_item_lay,R.id.main_child_item_text, myList);
    myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Am I missing something here?

EDIT: The layout (simplified):

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/widget_show_task_act_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Loading..."
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/widget_show_task_act_subtasks_listview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/widget_show_task_act_text" />
```

EDIT2:
I forgot to tell you guys that the Activity is started from a screen widget. Thus should I use getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext() ?

Comment: Add your layout to see if there is anything wrong there.

Comment: I would also add the TextView Layout (for the adapter), but generally they work for other adapters so the problem I suppose isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the bottom constraint for the Listview, and the height is 0.

For the ListView, contraint the bottom to the bottom of parent or some other widget that is already constrained.

Comment: Gosh I hate that Constraint Layout... Anyway I solved he problem in a very simple way. I set static height to the listview. Not the best solution but it will work for now, before I start learning the ConstraitLayout in depth.

Answer (score 0):

try like below:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: static height for the listview does the job.